# Why is the initial value to the reduce function not mandatory?

Tags: python, functional-programming

In haskell, the initial value for the `foldl` operator is clearly mandatory

```
Prelude> foldl (+) 0 [1]
1
Prelude> foldl (+) 0 []
0
Prelude> :t foldl
(a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

But in the reduce function (or `functools.reduce`), the initial value is optional

```
reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value
```

The only time the initial value is required is when the sequence is empty. That is congruent with the behaviour in haskell. Does `reduce` in python assumes that if the sequence is of size 1; then it handles these corner cases internally ?

```
>> reduce(operator.sub, [1])
1
>> reduce(operator.mul, [1])
1
>> reduce(operator.add, [1])
1
```

Comment: In Haskell, `foldl1` does not require an initial value either.

Comment: Note that there is a more Pythonic one-line spelling for the last one: `sum([1])`. The other cases are debatable (I mean, you *could* do `a[0] + sum(-b for b in a[1:])`, but I'd guess most wouldn't) , but its *usually* considered preferable to write the accumulator loop out explicitly. Python isn't really a functional language, its an OO language with some functional-ish features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [manual](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce):

> If *initializer* is not given and *iterable* contains only one item, the
>   first item is returned

---

I also want to comment on this:

> The only time the initial value is required is when the sequence is
>   empty

This is not entirely true. In a fold operation you usually always assume that you have an earlier result to work with. If your fold operation is appending elements to a list the initial element can be the empty list, so you can add elements to that. More generally, the initial value is always needed when the return type of the function differs from the type of the elements in the list.

Answer (score 6):

Recall that in Haskell there are two versions of folds - one that takes a seed of some result type, and one that assumes the seed is the first element of the sequence.

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr k z = go
        where
            go []     = z
            go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

and

```
foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
foldr1 _ [x]            =  x
foldr1 f (x:xs)         =  f x (foldr1 f xs)
foldr1 _ []             =  errorEmptyList "foldr1"
```

`foldr` uses the initial element of the sequence as the first state.

There is one other important difference: by using the first element of the sequence as the input state, `foldr1` is constrained to return an array of the same type as the input list. `foldr` however can return some different type.